# Typical usability tests when evaluating an ebook

Tags: usability-testing, books

I am attempting to do a usability test on an ebook. The current book is in the epub format but my usability test should be reusable in other formats as well. What are some of the areas I should focus on?

Currently I have the following:

- Navigation inside the book
- Accessibility (visually impaired users)
- Technical limitations

What else can be focused on in a usability test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some of the things I would look at

1. How does it scale across different orientations (landscape and portrait)
2. Does it allow for easily customization of content
3. Access to help about the ebook
4. Availability of accelerators to allow for quick access within a book (like to a particular page)
5. Design consistency

I also recommend looking at this [article about best practices for publishing your e-book](http://www.free-ebooks.net/blog/best-practice-tips-for-formatting-ebooks/)

> - Try to stick to one format throughout your text. Switching fonts,
>     paragraph styles, and other elements within your text can give an
>     unpolished look.
> - Use fonts that are widely used on computers and eReaders everywhere.
>     You can find a list of common fonts on the web, but here’s a standard
>     list. Try and use a font that has both a Windows and a Mac version.
> - Use low resolution .png or .jpg files for your images. High resolution images can inflate the total size of your eBook and that
>     will frustrate readers when they download to their computer or
>     eReader.
> - Page numbers and headings are not fixed for eReaders If you use them, be aware that you can have page numbers and headings appearing
>     embedded in your pages at odd and irregular places throughout the
>     text.

Comment: When you say customization of content, do you mean things like changing to font, adding highlight etc?

Comment: I mean like adding comments and annotations